# Echoing a text file with a scanner and have it double spaced?

Tags: java

I have to create a EchoDouble class that extends the Echo class which echos a text file to the console.

The contents of this said text file is

```
Nature's first green is gold, 
Her hardest hue to hold. 
Her early leaf's a flower; 
But only so an hour.
```

but i'm trying to edit the processLine method in the EchoDouble class so that it will echo back the text file double spaced like this

```
Nature's first green is gold, 

Her hardest hue to hold. 

Her early leaf's a flower; 

But only so an hour.
```

**Echo Class**

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.*;

    public class Echo{
      String fileName; // external file name
      Scanner scan; // Scanner object for reading from external file

      public Echo(String f) throws IOException
      {
        fileName = f;
        scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
      }

      // reads lines, hands each to processLine
      public void readLines(){
        while(scan.hasNext()){
          processLine(scan.nextLine());
        }
        scan.close();
      }

      // does the real processing work
      public void processLine(String line){
        System.out.println(line);
      }
    }
```

**EchoDouble Class**

```
import java.io.*;

public class EchoDouble extends Echo
{
  public EchoDouble (String datafile) throws IOException
  {
    super(datafile);
  }

  // Prints the given line and inserts a blank line
  // Overrides the processLine method in Echo class
  public void processLine(String line)
  {
    /* **code here** */
  }
}
```

I'm new to this echoing and scanner in java and am stuck on this problem. If anyone can give me any advice on how to approach this problem it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
@Override
public void processLine(String line){
     System.out.println(line);
     System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Wow that was so simple, don't know why I didnt think of that! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do would be:

```
public void processLine(String line) {
  System.out.println(line);
  System.out.println();
}
```

but that will give you an extra empty line at the end. Alternatively,

```
public void processLine(String line) {
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

will give you an extra empty line at the beginning. So you need a concept of whether it's the first line or not.

You could put that knowledge in `processLine`:

```
private boolean printedAnythingYet = false;
public void processLine(String line) {
  if (printedAnythingYet) {
    System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.println(line);
  printedAnythingYet = true;
}
```

Or in your `readLines`:

```
public void readLines() {
  boolean isFirstLine = true;
  while (scan.hasNext()) {
    processLine(scan.nextLine(), isFirstLine);
    isFirstLine = false;
  }
  scan.close();
}

public void processLine(String line, boolean isFirstLine) {
  if (!isFirstLine) {
    System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

I'm not sure which of those I like better. To be honest, I don't think `processLine` should be `public`.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
public void processLine(String line){
     System.out.println("\n" + line);
}
```

The \n is what creates a new line, then it echoes.